# Struts2 bootstrap select tag buffer overflow issue

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2 bootstrap plugin and Struts v2.5.10.1.

I am facing the issue as given below. I tried to find some solution for this but no luck yet. I guess if we find a way to override the DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE(which is set as 8192 in `FastByteArrayOutputStream`), then it shall resolve this issue.

> Two methods with same method signature but not providing classes assignable? "public abstract boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()" and "public boolean java.util.AbstractCollection.isEmpty()" please report!
>   May 04, 2017 4:52:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.nio.BufferOverflowException at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189) at org.apache.struts2.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.decodeAndWriteOut(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:150) at org.apache.struts2.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) at org.apache.struts2.components.Include.include(Include.java:260) at org.apache.struts2.components.Include.end(Include.java:153) at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)

Comment: When does it happen? Show your code.

Comment: In the code, there is nothing special. I am trying to include several JSP pages inside a parent JSP. But, there is 1 particular JSP page in  which its containing a select tag that displays an object containing huge list of options. I tried to check the size() of that list and it came around 188. If I reduce the size of that list to around 10 options then the entire page is loading fine and also the remaining included JSP pages are also being rendered fine. Could you please suggest some solution based on this explanation?

Comment: The issue got resolved at our end. The list contained few special characters. I changed the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in struts.properties file and it worked. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your time and support.